# Error en una tabla

Tags: c++

Necesito entrar varios datos de alumnos, entre ellos un DNI, pero a la hora de intentar mostrarlos estos se van acumulando, doy un ejemplo:

Ingreso el numero 123456 para el primer alumno y el numero 654321 para el segundo, al intentar mostrarlo en la lista al primer alumno aparece que su numero es "123456654321" y así sucesivamente mientras mas repeticiones del `for` haya.

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void b () {cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;}
void menu () {cout<<" * MENU DE OPCIONES DEL SISTEMA * "<<endl;}


int main(){

    int a, i;

    char nom [5][12];
    char ap [5][12];
    int edad [5] ;
    char tel [5] [11];
    char dni [5] [8];
    char sex [5] [12];

    char BUSapell [10];
    char BUSdni [10];
    int BUSBUS=0;

    for (i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){

        b ();

        cout<<"Ingresar nombre:";cin>>nom[i];

        cout<<"Ingresar apellido:";cin>>ap[i];

        cout<<"Ingresar DNI:";cin>>dni[i];

        cout<<"Ingresar edad:";cin>>edad[i];

        if (edad[i] >= 26 ){

            cout<<"Esa edad no es valida, se necesita tener 25 o menos años"<<endl;
            cout<<"Pruebe de nuevo: ";cin>>edad[i];

        }

        cout<<"Ingresar sexo:";cin>>sex[i];

        cout<<"Ingresar telefono fijo (0220):";cin>>tel[i];
    }

    b ();

    menu ();

    b ();

    do{

    cout<<"[1]  - Listado de alumnos ordenados de forma ascendente. \n";
    cout<<"[2]  - Busqueda de alumnos por Apellido  \n";
    cout<<"[3]  - Busqueda de alumnos por DNI  \n";
    cout<<"[4]  - Salir de la aplicación \n";

     cout<<"ingrese una opcion: ";cin>>a;

     switch (a) {

         case 1:

         for (i=0;i<2;i++) {

             b ();

             cout<<"Nombre y apellido: "<<nom[i]<<" "<<ap[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"DNI: "<<dni[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Edad: "<<edad[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Sexo: "<<sex[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Numero de telefono: "<<tel[i]<<endl;
             } break;

        case 2:

         cout<<"Colocar apellido: ";cin>>BUSapell;
     for (int i=0; i<2 ; i++ ){

         if (strcmp(ap[i],BUSapell)==0){

             b ();

             cout<<"Nombre y apellido: "<<nom[i]<<" "<<ap[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"DNI: "<<dni[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Edad: "<<edad [i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Sexo: "<<sex[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Numero de telefono: "<<tel[i]<<endl;
              }  } break;


        case 3:

        b ();

        cout<<"Colocar DNI: ";cin>>BUSdni;

        for (int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){

            BUSBUS = strcmp (dni[i],BUSdni);

            if (BUSBUS==0){

                b ();

              cout<<"Nombre y apellido: "<<nom[i]<<" "<<ap[i]<<endl;
              cout<<"DNI: "<<dni[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Edad: "<<edad [i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Sexo: "<<sex[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Numero de telefono: "<<tel[i]<<endl;

            }
        } break;

         /*cout<<"Colocar DNI: ";cin>>BUSdni;

        for (int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){

            if (strcmp(dni[i],BUSdni)==1){

                b ();

              cout<<"Nombre y apellido: "<<nom[i]<<" "<<ap[i]<<endl;
              cout<<"DNI: "<<dni[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Edad: "<<edad [i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Sexo: "<<sex[i]<<endl;
             cout<<"Numero de telefono: "<<tel[i]<<endl;
               }  } break; */


        case 4:

        b ();

        cout<<"  "<<"¡Gracias por utilizar el programa!"<<"  "<<endl;


         }}while(a!=4);






    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No creo que te pase con `123456` sino más bien con `12345678` y el motivo es el tamaño de los arrays:

```
char dni [5] [8];
```

Aquí has declarado un array para 5 campos, admitiendo cada campo un máximo de 8 caracteres.

Por otro lado tenemos que en C++ una cadena de caracteres debe terminar **siempre** con el caracter nulo `\0`. Por esta razón **siempre** hay que sumarle una posición al tamaño de las cadenas de texto.

Es decir, si tu intención es almacenar cadenas de longitud 8 como máximo tendrás que declarar el array con capacidad para, al menos, 9 elementos:

```
char dni [5] [9];
```

También, dado que estás en C++, puedes optar por dejar de usar arrays de caracters y reemplazar estos usos por `std::string`. Esta clase propia de C++ se encarga de reservar el espacio que necesite para almacenar las cadenas de caracteres de forma totalmente transparente:

```
std::string dni[5]; // Ya no hay que indicar el tamaño de cada string
```

Además, a puestos, podrías agrupar los datos en estructuras para mejorar su legibilidad:

```
#define NUM_ALUMNOS 2

struct Alumno
{
    std::string nombre;
    std::string apelllidos;
    int edad;
    std::string telefono;
    std::string dni;
    std::string sexo;
};

int main()
{
    Alumno alumnos[NUM_ALUMNOS];

    for(int i=0; i<NUM_ALUMNOS; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingresar nombre: ";
        cin>>alumnos[i].nombre;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Agrupar los datos en estructuras te facilitará la tarea de mostrar los registros ordenados, ya que no tendrás que mantener correctamente ordenados 6 arrays diferentes sino únicamente uno. Es decir, los datos de cada alumno estarán siempre juntos